# Can not build Ubuntu Touch project in Ubuntu SDK

Tags: ubuntu-sdk

There is an error:

```
The project "name" has no active kit
```

so I can't click the **Run** button (it is not active). What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can run your app from the command line though.

1. Open a terminal
2. cd into the directory your project is located
3. `qmlscene ~/CurrencyConverter/CurrencyConverter.qml`

That would allow you to run your app but I don't know why it wouldn't run from within Ubuntu SDK.